# implode output does not gives proper output

Tags: php

This shows all the elements from an array in a string but without a separator. I used ',' as a separator in this code. And it does not work. How can i separate them with separator.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die("Database Connection failed.".mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db("test1",$con);
if(!$db)
{
    die("Database selection failed.".mysql_error());
}


$query = "select * from menu limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    //$menu_name = $row['m_name'];
    //$menu_image = $row['m_image'];
    $menu_name = array($row['m_name']);
    $menu_image = array($row['m_image']);

    echo implode(',',$menu_name);
    //echo "<img src='images/$menu_image' style='height:200px;width:200px;'>";
}
if(!$result)
{
    echo mysql_error;
}
```

?>

Comment: What's the output of your `$menu_name`?

Comment: ChickenkhosharollChickenKoshaWithLacchaParathachickenmayorollgththcheckenmauttonfish ani rollllMyrollsa

Comment: If you want to store all names in a comma separated string that comes from $result query then you need to change little bit..

Comment: Is it `implode()` or the SQL query giving the wrong results? Please clarify your question and reduce the code to the bare minimum (but *not* less!) required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are storing array into variable . so if you will use imploade on an variable it will not show the result so best way is to store your result into an array and then use `implode` .

> Don't use depricated `mysql_*` function use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`
>   instead

```
$menu_image=array(); // start array to store
$menu_name=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $menu_name[] = $row['m_name'];   // store menu name 
    $menu_image[] = $row['m_image']; // store menu image

}
echo implode(',',$menu_name);  // finaly use implode
```

Comment: You need to `mysqli_fetch_array` into `mysql_fetch_array` @ShowStopper

Comment: @NarendraSisodia `mysql_*` is depricated function .

Comment: @ShowStopper I know that but OP is using the deprecated version and this'll lead to mixing of two API's

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$menu_name[];
$menu_image[];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];

$menu_name[] = $row['m_name']; // I change your $menu_name into an array so that when you fetch $row['m_name'] it returns an array
$menu_image[] = $row['m_image']; //same thing


}

 echo implode(',',$menu_name);
   //echo "<img src='images/$menu_image' style='height:200px;width:200px;'>";
```

Comment: I have done it. It gives a notice array to a string conversion with no output

Comment: What's the result of your `$row`?

Comment: i got it. Was forgot to change $menu_name = array($row['m_name']);

Answer (score 0):

try this in place of your while loop

```
 $menu_name = array();
 $menu_image = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $menu_name[] = $row['m_name'];
    $menu_image[] = $row['m_image'];



}
    echo implode(',',$menu_name);
```

Comment: use print_r(implode(',',$menu_name)); and show me the answer.

Comment: ohh no i got it. thnk u